# Parsing Email Body with 7BIT Content-Transfer-Encoding - PHP

Tags: php, email, imap, decode

I've been implementing some PHP/IMAP-based email handling functionality lately, and have most everything working great, except for message body decoding (in some circumstances).

I think that, by now, I've half-memorized [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) (the 'Internet Message Format' document guidelines), read through email-handling code for half a dozen open source CMSes, and read a bajillion forum posts, blog posts, etc. dealing with handling email in PHP.

I've also forked and completely rewritten a class for PHP, [Imap](https://github.com/geerlingguy/Imap), and the class handles email respectably well—I have some helpful methods in there to detect autoresponders (for out of office, old addresses, etc.), decode base64 and 8bit messages, etc.

**However, the one thing I simply can't get to work reliably (or, sometimes, at all) is when a message comes in with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`.**

It seems that different email clients/services interpret `7BIT` to mean different things. I've gotten some emails that are supposedly `7BIT` that are *actually* Base64-encoded. I've gotten some that are *actually* quoted-printable-encoded. And some that are not encoded in any way whatsoever. And some that are HTML, but aren't indicated as being HTML, and they're also listed as `7BIT`...

Here are a few examples (snips) of message bodies received with 7Bit encodings:

1:

```
A random message=20

Sent from my iPhone
```

2:

```
PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6dj0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTp2bWwi
IHhtbG5zOm89InVybjpzY2hlbWFzLW1pY3Jvc29mdC1jb206b2ZmaWNlOm9m
```

3:

```
tangerine apricot pepper.=0A=C2=A0=0ALet me know if you have any availabili=
ty over the next month or so. =0A=C2=A0=0AThank you,=0ANames Withheld=0A908=
-319-5916=0A=C2=A0=0A=C2=A0=0A=C2=A0=0A=0A=0A______________________________=
__=0AFrom: Names Witheld =0ATo: Names Withheld=
```

These are **all** sent with '7Bit' encodings (well, at least according to PHP/`imap_*`), but they're obviously in need of more decoding before I can pass them along as plaintext. Is there any way to reliably convert all messages with supposedly-7Bit encodings to plaintext?

Comment: If everyone just sent plaintext email, and used a nice, simple client like Mail for iOS, or `mail` on the command line, the world would be a better place :)

Comment: Those are broken messages.  7-bit means plain ascii: all characters in the message should be plain US-ASCII, with no additional encoding.  Something there is lying to you.  You can certainly try to do heuristic detection.

Comment: Also, you should pull the original MIME message down with a client like Thunderbird or something and look at it to make sure something in PHP isn't lying to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After spending a bit more time, I decided to just write up some heuristic detection, as Max suggested in the comments on my original question.

I've built a more robust `decode7Bit()` method in [Imap.php](https://github.com/geerlingguy/Imap/blob/c4b54e52576bf71a93045d2a4581589eab9a00b6/JJG/Imap.php#L398), which goes through a bunch of common encoded characters (like `=A0`) and replaces them with their UTF-8 equivalents, and then also decodes messages if they look like they are base64-encoded:

```
/**
 * Decodes 7-Bit text.
 *
 * PHP seems to think that most emails are 7BIT-encoded, therefore this
 * decoding method assumes that text passed through may actually be base64-
 * encoded, quoted-printable encoded, or just plain text. Instead of passing
 * the email directly through a particular decoding function, this method
 * runs through a bunch of common encoding schemes to try to decode everything
 * and simply end up with something *resembling* plain text.
 *
 * Results are not guaranteed, but it's pretty good at what it does.
 *
 * @param $text (string)
 *   7-Bit text to convert.
 *
 * @return (string)
 *   Decoded text.
 */
public function decode7Bit($text) {
  // If there are no spaces on the first line, assume that the body is
  // actually base64-encoded, and decode it.
  $lines = explode("\r\n", $text);
  $first_line_words = explode(' ', $lines[0]);
  if ($first_line_words[0] == $lines[0]) {
    $text = base64_decode($text);
  }

  // Manually convert common encoded characters into their UTF-8 equivalents.
  $characters = array(
    '=20' => ' ', // space.
    '=E2=80=99' => "'", // single quote.
    '=0A' => "\r\n", // line break.
    '=A0' => ' ', // non-breaking space.
    '=C2=A0' => ' ', // non-breaking space.
    "=\r\n" => '', // joined line.
    '=E2=80=A6' => '…', // ellipsis.
    '=E2=80=A2' => '•', // bullet.
  );

  // Loop through the encoded characters and replace any that are found.
  foreach ($characters as $key => $value) {
    $text = str_replace($key, $value, $text);
  }

  return $text;
}
```

This was taken from version 1.0-beta2 of the [Imap class for PHP](https://github.com/geerlingguy/Imap) that I have on GitHub.

If you have any ideas for making this more efficient, let me know. I originally tried running everything through `quoted_printable_decode()`, but sometimes PHP would throw exceptions that were vague and unhelpful, so I gave up on that approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. Good explanation and well commented. I appreciate that.

Comment: I love it-- This is a very simple str_replace() solution to this problem in PHP, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question.... But I am running into this issue now and it seems that PHP have a solution now.

this function [imap_fetchstructure()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) will give you the type of encoding.

```
0   7BIT
1   8BIT
2   BINARY
3   BASE64
4   QUOTED-PRINTABLE
5   OTHER
```

from there you should be able to create a function like this to decode the message

```
function _encodeMessage($msg, $type){

            if($type == 0){
                return mb_convert_encoding($msg, "UTF-8", "auto");
            } elseif($type == 1){
                return imap_8bit($msg); //imap_utf8
            } elseif($type == 2){
                return imap_base64(imap_binary($msg));
            } elseif($type == 3){
                return imap_base64($msg);
            } elseif($type == 4){
                return imap_qprint($msg);
                //return quoted_printable_decode($msg);
            } else {
                return $msg;
            }
        }
```

and you can call this function like so

```
$struct = imap_fetchstructure($conn, $messageNumber, 0);
$message = imap_fetchbody($conn, $messageNumber, 1);
$message = _encodeMessage($message, $struct->encoding);
echo $message;
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Note that this is the technique I'm using in the [Imap](https://github.com/geerlingguy/Imap) library mentioned in my answer; however, PHP almost always says a message is 7BIT encoded, even if it's not, so it's often necessary to do the manual decoding mentioned in my answer :(

Answer (score 0):

`$structure = imap_fetchstructure;`
NOT `$encoding = $structure->encoding`
BUT `$encoding = $structure->parts[ $p ]->encoding`

I think I had the same problem, now it's solved. (7bit didn't convert to UTF-8, kept getting ASCII) I thought I had 7bit, but changing the code to "BUT" I got `$encoding=4`, not `$encoding=0` which means that I have to `imap_qprint($body)` and `mb_convert_encoding($body, 'UTF-8', $charset)` to get what I wanted.

Anyway check the encoding number!! ( should be 4 not zero )

Comment: this is clearly incomplete code... what is $p supposed to represent? `$encoding = $structure->parts[ $p ]->encoding` will return $p as undefined.