# How to remove mimepart from received emails in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

I am using

```
$body_msg = imap_utf8(imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$mail, 1.2)));
```

to fetch my html emails in codeigniter in a formatted way  .

Issue I am facing is  :

I get some mimepart below the body of the email  .

For example - For an email I got -

```
----==_mimepart_579ff252a2fa2_7eceacb00c2643b--
```

below the email signatures used in the email  ,  How should I filter  / get rid of this content  .

Comment: try using a full on email parser class instead of the imap functions. ive had good luck with this:  https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721410/best-way-to-handle-email-parsing-decoding-in-php

Comment: Thank You mate  for the prompt reply , I will try the above . Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the error  , referring the below urls :

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Entire_message_fetched_when_opening_a_IMAP_message

[Parsing Email Body with 7BIT Content-Transfer-Encoding - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682208/parsing-email-body-with-7bit-content-transfer-encoding-php)